# JasperReports Server Community Edition 5.1 external database authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, jasperserver

I am still new to *JasperReports Server* and *Spring* security technologies. 
I tried modifying the *sample-applicationContext-externalAuth-db.xml* file provided with jasper server, and deploying it to the *WEB-INF* folder in the *jasperserver.war* file, according to the *jasperreportsserver-auth-cookbook*. When I try to login to the *JR Server* using an user defined in my external database, I get the following error:

```
[org.springframework.security.event.authentication.LoggerListener] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)
Authentication event AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent: criser; 
details: org.springframework.security.ui.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504:
RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 8RGV5wfImGpJLM3NDsxx0Koc.undefined;
exception: Bad credentials.
```

My external database stores the passwords as plain text. Here is my *applicationContext-externalAuth-db.xml*:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- ########## External JDBC Auth ###########
      - Sample configuration of JasperServer authentication via an external database
    -->
    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationProcessingFilter" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.BaseAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager">
            <ref local="dbAuthenticationManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="externalDataSynchronizer">
            <ref local="externalDataSynchronizer"/>
        </property>

        <property name="sessionRegistry">
            <ref bean="sessionRegistry"/>
        </property>

        <property name="internalAuthenticationFailureUrl" value="/login.html?error=15"/>
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/loginsuccess.html"/>
        <property name="invalidateSessionOnSuccessfulAuthentication" value="true"/>
        <property name="migrateInvalidatedSessionAttributes" value="true"/>

    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationSoapProcessingFilter"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.DefaultAuthenticationSoapProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="dbAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="externalDataSynchronizer" ref="externalDataSynchronizer"/>

        <property name="invalidateSessionOnSuccessfulAuthentication" value="true"/>
        <property name="migrateInvalidatedSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyBasicProcessingFilter"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ExternalAuthBasicProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="dbAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="externalDataSynchronizer" ref="externalDataSynchronizer"/>

        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint">
            <ref local="basicProcessingFilterEntryPoint"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationRestProcessingFilter" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.DefaultAuthenticationRestProcessingFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager">
            <ref local="dbAuthenticationManager"/>
        </property>
        <property name="externalDataSynchronizer">
            <ref local="externalDataSynchronizer"/>
        </property>

        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/rest/login"/>
        <property name="invalidateSessionOnSuccessfulAuthentication" value="true"/>
        <property name="migrateInvalidatedSessionAttributes" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dbAuthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="externalDaoAuthenticationProvider"/>
                <ref bean="${bean.daoAuthenticationProvider}"/> 

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="externalDaoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService"><ref bean="externalUserDetailsService"/></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="externalUserDetailsService" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.db.ExternalJDBCUserDetailsService">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="externalDataSource"/>
        <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT USERNAME as username, PASSW as password, true as enabled from DEVELOPMENT.SYS_USERS where (LOCKED=FALSE OR LOCKED IS NULL) AND USERNAME = ?"/>
        <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT DISTINCT U.username as username, F.method_name as rolename FROM DEVELOPMENT.SYS_USERS U, DEVELOPMENT.SYS_USER_GROUP UG, DEVELOPMENT.SYS_GROUP_FUNCTION GF, DEVELOPMENT.SYS_FUNCTIONS F WHERE U.ID = UG.USER_ID AND UG.GROUP_ID = GF.GROUP_ID AND GF.FUNCTION_ID = F.ID AND f.METHOD_NAME = 'REPORT' AND U.USERNAME = ?"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- ########## External JDBC Auth ########### -->

    <!-- ############ Synchronizer ############ -->
    <bean id="externalDataSynchronizer"
          class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.ExternalDataSynchronizerImpl">
        <property name="externalUserDetailsService">
            <ref bean="externalUserDetailsService"/>
        </property>
        <property name="externalUserProcessors">
            <list>
                <ref local="externalUserSetupProcessor"/>
                <!-- Example processor for creating user folder.
                    Other custom processors can be created and
                    added to the list.-->
                <!--<ref local="externalUserFolderProcessor"/>-->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="abstractExternalProcessor" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.AbstractExternalUserProcessor" abstract="true">
        <property name="repositoryService" ref="${bean.repositoryService}"/>
        <property name="userAuthorityService" ref="${bean.userAuthorityService}"/>
        <property name="tenantService" ref="${bean.tenantService}"/>
        <property name="profileAttributeService" ref="profileAttributeService"/>
        <property name="objectPermissionService" ref="${bean.objectPermissionService}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="externalUserSetupProcessor" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.ExternalUserSetupProcessor" parent="abstractExternalProcessor">
        <property name="userAuthorityService">
            <ref bean="${bean.internalUserAuthorityService}"/>
        </property>

        <property name="organizationRoleMap">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key>
                        <value>ROLE_REPORT</value>
                    </key>
                        <value>ROLE_ADMIN</value>
                </entry>
                <!-- Mapping customers roles to JS roles Example -->
                <!--<entry>-->
                <!--<key>-->
                <!-- Сustomer role(with adding ROLE_ prefix) which need to be mapped to root JS roles -->
                <!--<value>ROLE_ADMIN</value>-->
                <!--</key>-->
                <!-- root JS role customer role to be mapped to -->
                <!--<value>ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR</value>-->
                <!--</entry>-->
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultInternalRoles">
            <list>
                <value>ROLE_USER</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="externalUserFolderProcessor" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.processors.ExternalUserFolderProcessor" parent="abstractExternalProcessor">
        <property name="repositoryService" ref="${bean.unsecureRepositoryService}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- ############ Synchronizer ############ -->


    <!-- ############## external dataSource ############### -->
    <bean id="externalDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.152:5432/development"/>
        <property name="username" value="master"/>
        <property name="password" value="password12"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- ############## external dataSource ############### -->

</beans>
```

I would please like to know why I am getting the "bad credentials" exception. I tried configuring *log4j.properties* in the *WEB-INF* folder in order to get more details regarding the issue, but i wasn't able to get any more output other than

```
17:01:07,153 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,152  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:228 - Custom ESAPI security configuration is used.

17:01:07,160 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,160  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:431 - Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.

17:01:07,168 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,167  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:527 - Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.

17:01:07,182 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,176  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:543 - Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\ESAPI.properties

17:01:07,185 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,184  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:563 - Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties

17:01:07,198 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,192  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:587 - Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\daniel.cristea) directory: C:\Users\daniel.cristea\esapi\ESAPI.properties

17:01:07,209 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,201  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:436 - Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed.

17:01:07,218 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,211  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:437 - Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.

17:01:07,251 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,244  WARN JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:652 - SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from 'esapi/' using current thread context class loader!

17:01:07,262 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,257  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:457 - Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.

17:01:07,271 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,264  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:527 - Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.

17:01:07,282 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,274  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:543 - Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: C:\Program Files\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\validation.properties

17:01:07,291 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,285  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:563 - Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\validation.properties

17:01:07,301 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,294  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:587 - Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\daniel.cristea) directory: C:\Users\daniel.cristea\esapi\validation.properties

17:01:07,312 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,304  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:462 - Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.

17:01:07,318 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,317  INFO JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:463 - Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.

17:01:07,346 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) 2013-08-10 17:01:07,345  WARN JSESAPISecurityConfiguration,http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2:652 - SUCCESSFULLY LOADED validation.properties via the CLASSPATH from 'esapi/' using current thread context class loader!
```

I would like to know if there is any way in which I could figure out the source of the "Bad credentials" error.

Comment: Try adding `log4j.logger.com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth=DEBUG` to `log4j.properties` and then see what the logs report when you log in.

Comment: I'be tried adding log4j.logger.com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth=DEBUG to log4j.properties, but the logs report didn't change.
i forgot to mention i get two warnings:

Comment: 16:48:12,803 WARN  [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.JSDelegatingFilterProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) Filter proxy bean proxyAuthenticationProcessingFilter discovered.

16:48:12,806 WARN  [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.security.externalAuth.JSDelegatingFilterProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) proxyExceptionTranslationFilter bean was not "dropped into" application context.  Using class org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter instead.